# Grok parse failure but worked fine in grok constructor?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

My logs are like this:

```
[2017-05-17 22:22:55,708][WARN ][index.indexing.slowlog.index] [Torpedo][bank][1] took[101.4ms], took_millis[101], type[detail], id[88], routing[] , source[{"account_number":25,"balance":40540,"firstname":"Virginia","lastname":"Ayala","age":39,"gender":"F","address":"171 Putnam Avenue","employer":"Filodyne","email":"virginiaayala@filodyne.com","city":"Nicholson","state":"PA"}]
[2017-05-17 22:23:35,292][WARN ][index.indexing.slowlog.index] [Torpedo][bank][4] took[10.4ms], took_millis[10], type[detail], id[69], routing[] , source[{"account_number":25,"balance":40540,"firstname":"Virginia","lastname":"Ayala","age":39,"gender":"F","address":"171 Putnam Avenue","employer":"Filodyne","email":"virginiaayala@filodyne.com","city":"Nicholson","state":"PA"}]
```

MY grok is like this:

```
filter {
           grok {
                match => [ "message", "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:QUERY}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:QUERY1}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:INDEX-NAME}\]\[%{DATA:SHARD}\]%{SPACE}took\[%{DATA:TOOK}\],%{SPACE}took_millis\[%{DATA:TOOKM}\], type\[%{DATA:type}\], id\[%{NUMBER:id}\], routing\[%{DATA:routing}\], source\[%{DATA:source}\],"]
           }
    }
```

When i checked in [grokconstructor site](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result) it is showing it as matched .

```
[2017-05-17 22:22:55,708][WARN ][index.indexing.slowlog.index] [Torpedo][bank][1] took[101.4ms], took_millis[101], type[detail], id[88], routing[], source[{"account_number":25,"balance":40540,"firstname":"Virginia","lastname":"Ayala","age":39,"gender":"F","address":"171 Putnam Avenue","employer":"Filodyne","email":"virginiaayala@filodyne.com","city":"Nicholson","state":"PA"}]
MATCHED
source  {"account_number":25,"balance":40540,"firstname":"Virginia","lastname":"Ayala","age":39,"gender":"F","address":"171·Putnam·Avenue","employer":"Filodyne","email":"virginiaayala@filodyne.com","city":"Nicholson","state":"PA"}
INDEX-NAME  bank
SHARD   1
QUERY   index.indexing.slowlog.index
LEVEL   WARN
id  88
TOOK    101.4ms
TOOKM   101
routing 
TIMESTAMP   2017-05-17·22:22:55,708
QUERY1  Torpedo
type    detail
before match:   [
```

When i did through logstash it is throwing error like this:

```
 "message" => "[2017-05-17 22:23:35,292][WARN ][index.indexing.slowlog.index] [Torpedo][bank][4] took[10.4ms], took_millis[10], type[detail], id[69], routing[] , source[{\"account_number\":25,\"balance\":40540,\"firstname\":\"Virginia\",\"lastname\":\"Ayala\",\"age\":39,\"gender\":\"F\",\"address\":\"171 Putnam Avenue\",\"employer\":\"Filodyne\",\"email\":\"virginiaayala@filodyne.com\",\"city\":\"Nicholson\",\"state\":\"PA\"}]\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2017-05-17T17:35:36.287Z",
          "path" => "F:\\logstash-2.4.0\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\index.txt",
          "host" => "yaswanth",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
```

How can i avoid this?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

`routing[] ,`

After routing field i forgot to keep the space (i.e.%{SPACE}). That's the error.